# Error while decoding raw in Python

Tags: python, json, rest, python-unittest

I am trying to write PyUnit test, where i am passing the URL to the test and the test needs to fetch the data and decode. The data is coming as raw payload. We are using REST. Here is the test code i have written :

```
#import urllib
import urllib.request
import json

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://local:8080"})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

request = urllib.request.Request("http://test.com/1")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
encoding = response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
data = json.loads(response.read().decode(encoding))
print (data)
```

The problem is that i am getting the following error :

```
data = json.loads(response.read().decode(encoding))
```

> File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 318, in loads
>           return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>       File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
>           obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>       File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
>           raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None 
>       ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Could someone help ? Thanks in advance.

Regards
Amit

Comment: Try breaking the line that begins with `data = ...` into smaller parts. I'm having a hard time reading your stack trace, but there seems to be a `None` that slipped in somewhere. If you try reading the data into a variable, then decoding, then parsing the JSON you can log the intermediate results (or step through it in your debugger) to see where things go wrong.

Comment: did you try printing `response.read().decode(encoding)` and saw what the data was

Comment: The very first character of the data is not matching what `json` expects. As Vignesh says, you should print the data you receive to confirm that it's valid.

Comment: I tried that, somehow i feel that the data getting printed are related mostly to the network information in which i am not interested. I tried using the proxy code then i got the following error :                                    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
in getaddrinfo socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed.                  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Comment: In non corporate network, i don't get the network error, also the desired json is getting displayed but i get another error :       File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)